# Show that $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology on $X$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be an infinite set and $\mathcal T$ a topology on $X$ that contains every infinite subset of $X$. Prove that $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology.

Let $x \in X$, then $X\setminus \{x\}$ is an infinite subset of $X$ and so $X\setminus \{x \} \in \mathcal T$. Now $$\underbrace{X}_{open} = \{x \} \cup \underbrace{(X\setminus\{x\})}_{open}.$$ So we must have that $\{x\} \in \mathcal T$, i.e. $\mathcal T$ is the discrete topology on $X$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No. If you know that $A$ and $B$ are both open, you can conclude that $A\cup B$ is open as well. But here your reasoning is that because $B$ and $A\cup B$ are both open then $A$ is open as well. This is not usually true.  Think of open subsets of the real line, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you just proved that $\{x\}$ is closed.

Consider a partition of $X$ into two infinite disjoint subsets (see later), $X=A\cup B$. Let $x\in X$; then
$$
(A\cup\{x\})\cap(B\cup\{x\})=\dots
$$

How do you find $A$ and $B$? If $X$ is countable, then there is a bijection $f\colon\mathbb{N}\to X$; take as $A$ the image of the even numbers and for $B$ the image of the odd numbers. If $X$ is uncountable, take for $A$ a countable subset and for $B$ the complement of $A$.